# How to recover remote desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, session-restore

I have access to PSTools but when I connect to the target using RDP - I get black screen.

I tried:

```
psexec -u user -p password \\target C:\windows\system32\reset session 2
```

but then when I re-connect to the RDP it's a new session and I don't want that - I want to keep the current session alive. How can I achieve that?

I tried restarting as another option:

```
psservice -u user -p password \\target restart termservice
```

but it says it can't restart since other services depends on it.

```
Error controlling termservice on \\target :
A stop control has been sent to a service that other running services are dependent on.
```

I'm ending the session using:

```
tscon 2 /dest:console
```

Comment: Fix the problem with the blank screen instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: @Appleoddity This is what I want to do - if it aint obvious from the question.

Comment: It’s not obvious. You are trying to recover from a problem that shouldn’t happen in the first place. When I reconnect to an RDP session my screens are never blank.

Comment: @Appleoddity Well they are black because I spawn thousands of processes on the host - however I can do whatever I want on a 20+ years old server OS - it should be stable enough. Also I kill all the hogging processes before trying to enter the session with pskill.